# Check if rotation of model has changed?

Tags: javascript, three.js

How would you check if the rotation of a model has changed?
tried:

```
 var oldRotate = this._target.quaternion;
  console.log('works returns vector3 quaternion: ', oldRotate);
   var newRotate = oldRotate;

      if (oldRotate != newRotate) {
             console.log('this isnt triggering');
     }
```

this doesn't work and yes it's in a 'loop'

also tried:

```
 var oldRotation = new THREE.Vector3();
      oldRotation.copy(controlObject.quaternion);
      
      controlObject.position.copy(pos);
      this._position.copy(pos);
  
      this._parent.SetPosition(this._position);
      this._parent.SetQuaternion(this._target.quaternion);
   
  
  
       var newRotation = new THREE.Vector3();
          newRotation.copy(controlObject.quaternion);
  
   console.log(oldRotation.equals(newRotation));
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare objects for equality using the `==`/`!=` operator. This will merely compare the references to the objects, not their values. You will need to compare using the `.equals` method.

Also, in your example, you're assigning `oldR` to `newRotate` directly. I'm not sure if you've not included some intervening code. Either way, you should also be using `.clone` otherwise the `!=` will never happen.

See: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Quaternion for information about the `clone` and `equals` methods.

Comment: i tried this and its always true:  var oldRotation = new THREE.Vector3();
      oldRotation.copy(controlObject.quaternion);
      
      
 
   
  
  
       var newRotation = new THREE.Vector3();
          newRotation.copy(controlObject.quaternion);
  
   console.log(oldRotation.equals(newRotation));

Comment: (1) You need to store current rotation, (2) process rotation (with the mouse/code?), (3) then check the current rotation with what you stored in (1). It's unclear from your question where you are doing each of these steps.